# Sharing MS Excel Sheet over network?

Tags: microsoft-excel, sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sharing Excel sheet over network?](https://superuser.com/questions/425832/sharing-excel-sheet-over-network)

Is it possible to have a Server PC running a MS Excel Sheet to which several Thin Clients will be connected via TCP/IP having Barcode Scanners? The scanner's should dump their Data in the MS Excel Sheet in a First Come First Server basis? At the end of the day, the Excel sheet will be saved in Server PC's hard drive.

And, is there any other alternatives to achieve the above requirement?

Barcode Scanners have USB Output.

Schematic Diagram: http://i45.tinypic.com/2qlesnl.png