# Sharing Excel sheet over network?

Tags: microsoft-excel, sql-server

Is it possible to have a server PC running a Microsoft Excel sheet to which several Thin Clients, with Barcode Scanners, will be connected via TCP/IP? The scanners should dump their data in the Excel sheet in a First Come First Served basis? At the end of the day, the Excel sheet will be saved on server PC's hard drive. The Barcode Scanners have a USB output.

And, are there any other alternatives to achieve the above requirement?

Schematic Diagram:

[image]

Comment: Barcode scaners have USB Output, and in what they are pluged in. Are they act as HIDs on some machine or they have own memory and mode to send data in other way

Comment: @adopilot, A person will scan a barcode, whose data will be passed through USB port. Need to dump it in Excel Sheet. just as the schematic diagrams shows.

Comment: I wonder how the requirement of excel came about, without being a db admin, but having experience connecting from outside to excel sheets, this sounds like the hardest way to achieve the goal.

Comment: Tbh, I don't think it will work. A web front-end done in php or some other server-side language, with a smattering of JavaScript and pointing to a database would be a much better solution (providing the skill-set is there of course).

Answer (score 3):

If you try and access an Excel Spreadsheet (or Access Database) with more than one user you are very likely to run into filesharing or permission issues, I would reccomend using something like MySQL that would support it. You have to bear in mind with Thin Clients that, as they are a stripped-down OS they may not have the drivers for the barcode scanners - there's probably better ways of doing what you want.

Comment: Oh, so what if I plan to swap Thin Clients to small Computers running Windows XP? will that still work with MySQL running in Server? And multiple such small Computers can concurrently dump their data in the SQL Server?

Comment: Most barcode scanners tend to show up as a USB Keyboard (or at least have a mode to which you can set them and make them appear as a USB keyboard, so I wouldn't worry about that).

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using something like Google Docs / Office 365 as either of these two spreadsheet products are designed for collaboration?

Answer (score 0):

I have to agree with @tombull89 the sharing issues could be a mess.

Why not have each scanner write to a uniquely named csv file in a target network location, and have an excel template with a macro that appends them as a single file from that directory.

You would essentially process the scanned content into excel, and can rename or archive the original csv content out to a processed directory once they import.

Comment: Good idea, but can this be automated? And all those csv files will be added into one Excel sheet?

Comment: Yes you can create a macro that processes them. How many users are scanning? My suggestion is to have them all scan to individual files and have the macro read a selected directory into your excel file. How you are using this final excel final might be a question. If it is for a reconciliation of what should be you can then do comparisons etc.

Comment: There will be around 20 scanners(possibly more). So now, each will have their own individual Thin Clients through which they'll store their csv file in a common location in server right?(will this be possbile? as each will have different users created, since Thin Clients will link up through Remote Desktop Protocol) 

Then the excel's macro will processes them and create a single file? Seems good, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Excel 2003 and later has a feature called [shared workbooks](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/use-a-shared-workbook-to-collaborate-HP010096833.aspx). This should let you do what you want. It does come with certain limitations, but for your use case, these shouldn't be a problem.

Specifically, you cannot:

- Create an Excel table
- Insert or delete blocks of cells (you can only insert entire rows/columns)
- Delete worksheets
- Merge or split cells
- Add or change conditional formats
- Add or change data validation
- Create or change charts or PivotChart reports
- Insert or change pictures or other objects
- Insert or change hyperlinks
- Use drawing tools
- Assign, change, or remove passwords
- Protect or unprotect worksheets or the workbook
- Create, change, or view scenarios
- Group or outline data
- Insert automatic subtotals
- Create data tables
- Create or change PivotTable reports
- Write, record, edit, view or assign macros
- Add or change Microsoft Excel 4 dialog sheets
- Change or delete array formulas
- Use data form to add new data
- Work with XML data, including:

  - Import, refresh, and export XML data
  - Add, rename, or delete XML maps
  - Map cells to XML elements
  - Use the XML Source task pane, XML toolbar, or XML commands on the Data menu

You can of course access all of these features again after you unshare the workbook.

Another option is to use [Sharepoint's Excel services REST API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh124646.aspx).

Though I'd personally just use a proper database as that's what you're really using the spreadsheet as. You can always use an Access/Jet database and then export to Excel spreadsheets, or you can use a MySQL DB and [connect to it using OpenOffice/LibreOffice Base and export the data to Calc and save as an ODS spreadsheet](http://user.services.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=42&t=28029).